# Ubuntu 22.04 - Autostart VirtualBox 7.0

Tags: virtualbox, autostart

I'm trying to start VM boxes automatically on boot. A quick search yield 2 main solutions:

- using Stat-up Application ([tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/mm40vs/how_to_autostart_vm_virtualbox_linux_ubuntu/)). No luck.
- using `systemd` service ( [tutorial](https://www.paulligocki.com/make-virtual-box-vm-autostart/)). Although when service was `start`ed using command-line, after boot - nothing happened.

and many more references on-line.

Appreciate any help for a working solution.

**Edit_1**

Can't explain why- but using first method DID do the job, but :

1. I need 2 VM to start at boot.
2. Only first VM starts (once only, the 2nd one did start).

Guy

Comment: Will the VMs need to start *before* anyone logs into the machine? If so, there will be some additional hurdles to make VirtualBox run under the `root` account, as there are checks in place to prevent that 

Comment: @matigo No. It's not ideal but user is auto-login (meaning that it does not wait for password after boot ).

Comment: Generally what I have done in the past (before moving from VMs to Docker containers), is use a script that runs after the main account logs in. You can start a VM from the command line, which makes it possible to have a script launch VMs in a specific order, and including wait time between launches. the `VBoxManage` command is quite versatile 

Comment: @matigo I sadly keep that in mind :)